# How do I make a custom world with advanced settings?

Tags: space-engineers

I want to make a custom world using the Star System scenario so that I have planet, and I want to change some advanced stuff.

I click 'New World' then 'Custom World'.
I then click 'Star System' as my base scenario.
I then click 'Advanced' and fill out what I want.
After this I hit 'Ok'. This brings me back to the 'Custom World' screen, where the scenario is set to 'Easy Start Earth'. The settings I can see are not what I chose. If I start at this point, it will not be what I chose. If I don't start and click advanced again, I see none of the choices I made there.

Comment: From what you said this sounds like a bug, better report it on the official SE forum here: http://forums.keenswh.com/forums/bug-reports.326950/

Comment: Its no longer giving me this issue. I tried the other day. Should i just delete this post?